# single quote vs no quote in C

Tags: c, char

in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c - '0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
        nwhite, nother);
}
```

I don't understand why replacing this line:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
```

with this line:

```
if (c >= 0 && c <= 9)
```

give different results? For example, when the code is written with the latter option and the user press the 9 button, the program see it not as a digit, but as "other".

Comment: Why the downvotes people?  This is a perfectly understandable and legitimate question.  Please remove your downvotes or explain them in comments so @O.d has a chance to address them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `'0'` is a character literal. Its exact value depends on the encoding used on your system, but in the most common encoding scheme (ASCII) we can check e.g. [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) and see that its value is `48` decimal.

The expression `0` on the other is an integer literal and has the value `0`.

Doing e.g. `0 == '0'` is the same as doing `0 == 48` which is definitely not true.

Comment: So when using '0' I look at the char column of the ASCII table, and when using 0 - the decimal column?

Comment: @O.d If you want to know the actual value of an ASCII encoded character, then look in the table. If you want to know the value of an integer literal like plain `0`, then that is its value. `0` is zero is `0`. The ***character*** `'0'` is not the same as the ***integer*** `0`. A character is a character, no matter what the characters actually is. Using your logic where `'0'` is the same as `0`, what would e.g. `'A'` be the same as? `A`?

Comment: So I get it that basically, when the user press the 0 button on his keyboard, the machine interprets it as a character literal '0'?

Comment: @O.d that is correct for **getchar()**. Make sure you read the manuals for the functions if you have an error like this. Using the correct types is very inportant in C. Not using them can sometimes work which is actually worse than not working at all ;)

Comment: @AlainO'Dea, thanks. What do you mean by manuals? I'm sorry, I pretty much stick to Kernighan and Ritchie's book, and what's not in there is sometimes kind of hard to know about.

Answer (score 3):

`'0'` is byte of 0x30, `'9'` is 0x39. But `0` and `9` are simply 0x00 and 0x09.

Comment: a follow-up question: If I would've write: `++ndigit[c - 0];` instead of `++ndigit[c - '0'];`, is there any meaning to this arithmetic subtraction?

Comment: @O.d If `c` is `char` type and its content is ASCII digit between `0` and `9`, by substracting `c - '0'` you get value 0..9. The other case `c - 0` has no meaning - X - 0 = X.

Comment: well, x-0=x has a meaning: x. So my question is why `c-0` give a different result from `c-'0'` (`c` is a `char`).

Comment: @O.d Because `c-'0'` is equivalent to `c - 0x30`. Every single quoted char is replaced with the ASCII code.

Comment: I now understand that the basic thing I don't understand is the ASCII arithmetic: `0x39 - 0x30` doesn't equal `0x09`, but `0x39`. So how does it work? Where can I read about this?
That's why I still don't understand why `c-0` is not an equivalent of x-0=x? For example, if `c` holds the value of `9` - because the user pressed the 9 button on his keyboard - shouldn't `c-0` be `0x39 - 0` and be equal to `0x39`?

Comment: @O.d To get value (index) between 0 and 9 from buttons "0".."9" you need `c - '0'` or `c - 0x30` or `c - 48`.

Comment: I understand that. I don't understand the way the subtraction operates. e.g., why `0x39 - 0x30` "equals" `0x39` and not `0x09`?

Comment: @O.d `0x39 - 0x30` equals 0x09.

Comment: OK, I understand it now. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the values are alphabetic characters but in the second case they are numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

Because '0' == 48. The value of character equals to it's number in ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

In your line of Code:

> /* after using a getchar() you don't get the value of C as 9 when you are pressing 9 instead you get ASCII 0x30+ 9 = 0x39.*/

1.when you give the comparison as:

```
if (c >= 0 && c <= 9)
++ndigit[c - '0'];
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
++nwhite;
else
++nother;
```

> /*your code will not pass the if as 0x39 > = 0 but not < = 9
>   and since its not ' ' or '\n' or '\t' so its going to the else part and other is getting incremented.*/

2.In the below case:

> /*Your getchar() will receive 0x39(9) as input and then you are doing the comparison:*/

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
```

> /* value of c is 0x39 and '0' is equal to c>0x30 and c<=0x39 so the condition is satisfied and you are increment the value at that digits position in digit counter*/

```
++ndigit[c - '0'];
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
++nwhite;
else
++nother;
```